# Grails: Add new attribute in select

Tags: grails

I want to add a new attribute in select tag of grails. Let's say the attribute name is "currencyId". How will I do that? or is that even possible?

I've tried this but it didn't work

> ```
> <div class="input_div">
>     <g:select name="${textFieldName}" from="${from}" class="commonSelectSize3Cols"
>               value="${instanceFieldValue}"
>               noSelection="${['': message(code: (noSelectionMessageCode ?: "noSelection.label"))]}"
>               optionKey="${optionKey}" optionValue="${optionValue}" ${newAttribute}="${newAttributeValue}" />
> </div>
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add it like any other HTML attribute:

```
<div class="input_div">
    <g:select name="${textFieldName}" from="${from}" class="commonSelectSize3Cols"
              value="${instanceFieldValue}"
              noSelection="${['': message(code: (noSelectionMessageCode ?: "noSelection.label"))]}"
              optionKey="${optionKey}" optionValue="${optionValue}" data-new-attribute="${newAttributeValue}" />
</div>
```

Since `g:select` doesn't use that attribute, it will simply pass it along undisturbed, so that it gets rendered.